# React-Native: Content Compression Resistance Priority

Tags: android, css, reactjs, react-native

I feel like I've reached the end of what's possible with React Native's flex layout and before I waste more hours trying to figure it out myself, I figured maybe you have an idea. This is what I want to do, what is super easy with iOS using Content Compression Resistance Priority:
[image]

You can see the following 4 requirements for this layout here:

1. Price is showing
2. Amount is showing
3. Amount is right next to the name
4. The name is cut off ("...") if it’s too long

If you take off the quantity label, this is very easy in react-native. But I'm lost with three labels.

Here's what I have been able to accomplish with React Native on Android:
[image]

As you can see here, the second one looks good because the name is not too long. But as soon as it's too long the quantity label is gone. I've tried everything I could find on the internet from min-width to flex shrink & grow in all kinds of variations but I guess I haven't found the right one yet.

Here's my code, any suggestion is appreciated!

```html
<View style={{
    height: 46,
    flexDirection:"row",
    marginHorizontal: 40,
    alignItems: "center"
}}
    key={"contribution" + contribution.id}
>
    <View style={{
        flexDirection: "row",
        flex: 1,
    }}>
        <Text style={{
                marginHorizontal: 0,
                backgroundColor: "purple"
            }}
            numberOfLines = {1}
        >
            Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2 Test2
        </Text>
        <Text style={{
                backgroundColor: "red",
                marginHorizontal: 0,
                flex: 1,
                marginLeft: 3
            }}
            numberOfLines = {1}
        >
            {"(" + contribution.amount + ")"}
        </Text>
    </View>
    <Text style={{
            backgroundColor: "blue",
            marginLeft: 10,
            marginHorizontal: 0
        }}
        numberOfLines = {1}
    >
        {"$" + def.utils.formatNumberWithCommas(contribution.amount)}
    </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: (in iOS) I suppose you have three labels. This can be achieved through hugging and resistance priorities.

1. Make your price label horizontal resistance priority up by 1 point.
2. Make your quantity label horizontal resistance priority up by 1 point and horizontal hugging priority 1 point down (Make sure alignment of label is left aligned).

Comment: how about setting maxWidth prop of the purple label?

Comment: @yangguang1029 thank you this worked! it's not ideal of course but fine for now.